# cloud storage API for streaming data

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-storage, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

What are the cloud data storage APIs that accomodate streaming data well?

Specifically, a constant data stream that: 1) has no known end and is continually appended to and 2) can be read from at any time.

Due to the nature of distributed access, the big cloud storage options like Amazon S3, Google Storage for Developers, and Windows Azure Blobs do not seem to support streaming data.

Current beliefs:

1) Amazon S3 does not allow append operations to objects (only replace).  The multipart upload API allows a "streaming" upload, but it requires to be "finalized" once completely written.

2) Google Storage objects are immutable, so same thing.

3) Windows Azure blog storage has has block storage, but like Amazon S3 multipart upload, requires the blocks to be "finalized" so an open-ended stream is not possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With Windows Azure blob storage, you can keep appending to the same blob (and committing the block list after each write) as long as you want, and you can request any byte range when reading. However, you still wouldn't get the behavior of a single HTTP request with data continually streaming down. (You'd have to request a range and then make another request for the next range, etc. In other words, at any given time, the blob has finite length.)

Building your own code to front-end the data (socket-based or maybe a chunked HTTP response) may be your only option, if I'm understanding the requirements correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that you could append to the blob after the initial write.  I think this largely solves my problem, although since yesterday I've also been looking at the Page mode.   Specifically just appending pages to the BLOB.  Do you see any issues with that approach?

Comment: I believe page blobs need to have predetermined (fixed) length, so you'll need to create a very large page blob and then gradually fill it. Block blobs can instead just get longer and longer (but you have to commit the entire list of blocks each time, so that list may get really long).

Comment: You only pay for the pages you have written though so there is no issue in just making a page blob that is a couple of TB and then just appending to it.  You might need to keep the length somewhere though, perhaps at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Windows Azure Page Blob, rather than a Block Blob.  For info about page blobs see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691964.aspx.

With a Page Blob you will be able to append to an existing blob, the main consideration is that you have to write whole 512 byte pages, so if you appending to an existing file you may have to also send up to 511 bytes of existing data from the end of your file.